# Self contained API hooking

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm writing an application which requires intercepting local API calls to override some default behavior in a control.

I have been able to implement what I need with EasyHook and everything works fine.
I was hoping to find a snippet to write my own API hooking routines so that I don't need to re-distribute third party dll's.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve: the fact that it is a 3rd party API and you want everything to be written by you or do you want a single exe you distribute for your file so the program can be without a installer.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H ? Other than that, hooks can be a bit tricky and will require some work. You yourself have to judge if it's work to write yourself or take the library. (It can of course also be an exercise)

Comment: Scott, I want to avoid having to depend on third party dlI(s) I have no control over and also I'd rather not deal with legal stuff that might come with redistributing someone else's work (even if it's free).

Comment: Alex, thanks for your suggestion. I need API hooking (hi-jacking) not Message hooking.